# How do check whether a DOM node inherits from a constructor?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I have a random DOM node and I want to determine whether it is an `svg` element, namely that is inherits from the `SVGElement` constructor. I know I could just walk up the prototype chain by calling `__proto__` on the node, but is there a built in method to determine this?

Comment: Do you have a node or a constructor of a specific node? For a node, `instanceof` should work (not sure if it does cross-browser).

Comment: @pimvdb yes i have the node and the constructor, thanks this works. Write an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the dedicated `instanceof` operator which checks whether an object has a constructor's prototype in its prototype chain:

```
node instanceof SVGElement
```

However, given that you cannot actually do `new SVGElement()` (as with all node constructors),  this may not work reliably across all browsers.